# Deriving with matrices, matrice equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Can someone do this stepwise so that I am able to see what is going on. I am sure there is not many steps to take, but I am struggling to see the logic that goes from the left hand side to the right.!
$$(X^T X)^{-1}X^T(\sigma^2I_n)X(X^TX)^{-1} = \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}$$

Comment: $\sigma$ is a scalar, right? if so it commutes with everything. You pull it out to the left and then everything else cancels.

Comment: Thats right, what do you mean by commutes?

Comment: Two things $a$,$b$ commute if $ab=ba$ ... Scalars commute with any matrix.

Comment: Okey, thanks. Also, while working on this I am trying to build a mathematical vocabulary. Is there any books that would give me a good definition for what commute would mean in regards to mathematics

Comment: That depends a lot on your background. I think any decent book on linear algebra should be helpful though.

Comment: I thought I got it but I am not able to see what cancels, could you show what represents A and B in this case and how it is canceled?

Comment: I'll write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as has already been said in the comments, you can pull the scalar $\sigma^2$ all the way to the left. In addition to this, we can leave off $I_n$ because it is the identity (i.e. it does nothing by definition). This gives us:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
(X^T X)^{-1}X^T(\sigma^2I_n)X(X^TX)^{-1} =& \sigma^2(X^T X)^{-1}X^TX(X^TX)^{-1} \\
=& \sigma^2(X^T X)^{-1}\underbrace{(X^TX)(X^TX)^{-1}}_{=I_n} \\
=& \sigma^2(X^T X)^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Which is what was to be shown.

Comment: Yees, I swear I get dumber and dumber! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @ALEXANDER No need to insult yourself. There are plenty of times that I don't see something immediately, and everyone learns at a different pace.